# What flags are set off in 40h + 40h when they are signed vs. unsigned?

Tags: assembly, binary, flags, unsigned, signed

For both of them my output is 1000 0000 (80h). Adding them in decimal is 64 + 64 = 128. 128 is in range if it is unsigned, out of range if it is signed.

So for unsigned the flags that should be set off are overflow flag (because MSB is negative when numbers added were positive) and sign flag (because MSB is 1).

For signed the overflow flag should be set off yet again (because 128 is out of range for 8 bit signed) and sign flag should be set to 1 because of MSB. The carry flag should not be set because a carry operation did not occur in the MSB bits. Is this correct? The flags set off for signed vs. unsigned in this case should be the same?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The cpu only does one addition, the signed/unsigned decision only determines which flags you use.

Comment: Depends on the architecture.  Which architecture are you programming for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one addition operation which sets flags for both the signed and unsigned effects of the operation.  Subtraction is the same (cmp is just a subtraction that discards the result, except for the flags)

- The V (overflow) flag captures a *signed* overflow.
- The C (carry) flag captures an *unsigned* overflow.
- The S (sign) flag captures the top bit of the result.
- The Z (zero) flags is set if all the result bits are 0.

That's it.  You look at different flags if you were doing an unsigned or a signed operation, depending on what you are trying to detect.

Comment: The OP didn't specify what architecture.  Those are the names of the flags on ARM (I think).  On x86 it would be OF / CF / SF / ZF.  But sure, I think we can assume a 2's complement architecture with flags equivalent to that, rather than one's complement or something where there would be a different instruction for signed addition.  We know it's not MIPS, because MIPS doesn't have flags.

Comment: Pretty much all flag-based architectures use these flags; how you abbreviate the names is largely irrelevant.  Some old machines call C the carry/borrow flag and reverse the sense of it for sub/cmp instructions to save a couple of gates in the CPU, but they still work in pretty much the same way,

Comment: Yes, that was kind of my point: the flags are the same on ISAs that have flags, but not all ISAs name them the same way.  (And some 8-bit ISAs don't have an OF / V signed-overflow flag).  And good point about C / CF being a borrow for sub/cmp, like on x86.  I just thought it was weird to use the ARM names without saying anything about it.

Comment: I tend to use these single character names even on x86 :-)

Comment: Good luck when you write `setv` or `jv` instead of `seto` or `jo`, then >.<  At least it doesn't assemble into something else, it's just invalid and fails noisily.